# Mobile network operator searching selection on demand in android?

Tags: android, networking, selection

I am doing one project where it requires to search mobile network operators available for current location by help of the application and registering the operator by  application pro grammatically?

Please help me to resolve the issue.

Thanx in advance

Comment: **NOT POSSIBLE**

 check this http://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/ConnectivityManager.html &

http://android.riteshsahu.com/tips/programmatically-get-the-current-network-operator-name

Comment: thanks for your quick response. is there any indirect method to achieve this? find the below link https://files.ifi.uzh.ch/CSG/staff/tsiaras/Extern/Publications/Automatic_and_On-demand_Mobile_Network_Operator_MNO_Selection_Mechanism_Demonstration_NOMS_2014.pdf